# How many namespace can a cluster k8s hold?

Tags: kubernetes

If I want to develop a SaaS system and want to use k8's namespace to do isolation, i.e., I will create a namespace for every user, it's a multi-tenancy system, then, how many namespaces can I have? Will k8s be slowdown when namespace increases?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To answer your question, namespace is a logical entity that is used to isolate the application environment from another application environment. It doesn't consume cluster resources like cpu and memory. Ideally you can create any number of namespaces. Am not sure if there is a limit on number of namespaces that is allowed in a custer

On the other hand it is not a good approach to have one namespace each for user. Applications multi tenancy should be better  handled in the application code itself. Namespace is recommended to isolate the environment like one for Development, one for TEST, one for QA and Another one for production

Comment: To refine this a bit, the only isolation that Namespaces provide on their own is Kubernetes object name collisions. The are not the same as network boundaries (NetworkPolicies) or permissions boundaries (RBAC).

Answer (score 0):

This is a pretty good write-up on some best-practices around namespaces and how to organize things with them:

https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/containers-kubernetes/kubernetes-best-practices-organizing-with-namespaces

There are likely use-cases where you can have too many namespaces, but it is very unlikely that you will see this unless you have a custom application or controller that is doing something unwise and needs some of its logic reworked.